# python: Can't get urllib.request to work in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I was following a tutorial online and came across this bit of code:

```
import random
import urllib.request


def download_web_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)

download_web_image("https://buckysroom.org/photos/users/2/resized/2463a86fdf42a1681c66ba8fd6789f9d.jpg")
```

I'm using PyCharm as my IDE and I'm getting traceback errors.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Please share the traceback errors so that we can help you.

Comment: It's to do with the functions within request.py; e.g
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1189, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
 

File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1090, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)

etc.

Comment: It probably would be best, if you edit the full traceback in your question. This makes it easier for us to fully understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this error prompts for python3.x as there is no urllib module any more. Actually it divided into several modules.

**For python 3.x**

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrive("https://your url/name.jpg")
```

**For python 2.x**

```
urllib.urlopen
```

But in both version urlretrive works same so, no need to change anything in that part.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the ".request" from the import line and change this from
**urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)**
to
**urllib.urlretrieve(url, full_name)**

[See my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z3w9.png)